# Scala Generics : Cannot write an instance of T to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[T]

Tags: scala, generics, playframework

Following code when written using generic give a compilation error.

**Without Generic**

```
def getData(id: String) = Action.async {

    val items = getItems(id)

    sendResult(items)
  }

  private def sendResult(result: Future[Any]) = {


    result.map {
      items => {
        try {
          val itemStr = items.asInstanceOf[String]
          Ok(itemStr)
        } catch {
          case t: ClassCastException => InternalServerError(s"Casting Exception while processing output $t")
        }
      }
    }.recover {
      case t:TimeoutException => InternalServerError("Api Timed out")
      case t: Throwable => InternalServerError(s"Exception in the api $t")
    }
  }
```

**With Generic**

```
  def getData(id: String) = Action.async {

    val items = getItems(id)

    sendResult[String](items)
  }

  private def sendResult[T](result: Future[Any]) = {


    result.map {
      items => {
        try {
          val itemStr = items.asInstanceOf[T]
          Ok(itemStr)
        } catch {
          case t: ClassCastException => InternalServerError(s"Casting Exception while processing output $t")
        }
      }
    }.recover {
      case t:TimeoutException => InternalServerError("Api Timed out")
      case t: Throwable => InternalServerError(s"Exception in the api $t")
    }
  }
```

The code is part of play app's contorller method. First one works fine. Second one gives following compilation error

> Cannot write an instance of T to HTTP response. Try to define a
>   Writeable[T] [error]           Ok(itemStr) [error]

Comment: Play knows how to transform a String into a HTTP Response. But you give Play no way to do that using a generic type T. Check out https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActions#Simple-results

Comment: but at runtime i am providing the Type T to be of String.

Comment: Related, it isn't clear what you're trying to do. No matter what `items` is, you just seem to want a String version of it. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Any` with a generic function doesn't make much sense.

```
private def sendResult[T](result: Future[Any])
// Should better be
private def sendResult[T](result: Future[T])
// ... also remove the unsafe cast
```

Then this `T` needs to be provided an instance of `Writeable`, so it can be written a `Array[Byte]` over network.

```
// Either ...
private def sendResult[T: Writeable](result: Future[T])
// ... or ...
private def sendResult[T](result: Future[T])(implicit w: Writeable[T])
```

Comment: that works! however if i change the Ok(items) to Ok(Json.toJson(items) it breaks again with  "No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type." Something that is writeable should not be serializable by json?

Comment: @konquestor change the implicit `Writeable[T]` to `Writes[T]` from the JSON package

Answer (score 0):

The `Ok(...)` is calling the method `apply[C](content: C)(implicit writeable: Writeable[C]): Result` on `Status` class. You need to have an implicit value for `Writeable[T]` in scope.

As a side note, rather than using Future[Any], you may as well use Future[T] and remove the cast. Also you can use `Writes` for JSON serialization.

```
private def sendResult[T](result: Future[T])(implicit writeable: Writes[T]) = {
         result.map {
          items => {
            Ok(Json.toJson(items))                
          }
        }.recover {
          case t:TimeoutException => InternalServerError("Api Timed out")
          case t: Throwable => InternalServerError(s"Exception in the api $t")
        }
      }
```

Comment: so how is the implicit writeable passed to sendResult method?

Comment: @konquestor It should be passed... implicitly. In the case of the string, you should not have to do anything because it is already defined. If you were passing a custom structure, you would have add an `implicit val` in the scope where you make the call to sendResult (in the getData function, or in the class/object/module where these methods are defined).

Comment: i see the code breaks again if i change  Ok(items) to Ok(Json.toJson(items)) with error "No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type." If something is writeable should not that be json serializable?

Comment: yes it did. i have upvoted your answer i dont know why someone downvoted it.

Comment: @konquestor appreciated. if it worked for you, please select it as the accepted answer